# How to disable all buttons in the interface after callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following function

```
function draw(i, arrayIdColetor, callback) { 
  var query = new $kinvey.Query(); 
  query.equalTo('idColetor', arrayIdColetor[i]); 
  var promise = $kinvey.DataStore.find('myDatabase', query); 
  var latLong = promise.then(function(response) {
   coordenadas = []; 
   for(var j = response.length - 1; j >= 0 ; j--) {
    coordenadas.push( {lat: response[j].lat, lng: response[j].lng}); 
  }
  return coordenadas; 
}); 

  latLong.then(function(coordenadas) { 
    $kinvey.poly[i] = new google.maps.Polyline({ path: coordenadas, ... }); 
    $kinvey.poly[i].setMap($kinvey.map); });
  callback(); 
}
```

This function is called by the following function:

```
function callFor(j, arrayIdColetor) {
  if (j < arrayIdColetor.length){
    draw(j, arrayIdColetor, function() {
      callFor(j + 1, arrayIdColetor)
    });
    } 
}
```

The function callFor take a couple of seconds to be executed and I'd like that all the interface buttons be disabled while callFor functions is running. What should I do to solve it?

One more question, I have another function that I'd like that runs always after the callFor function is finished.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your title seems to be misleading after reading your description. It should be something like "How to disable all buttons in the interface after callback", or something along those lines.

Comment: I'm sorry @KФ. I followed your suggestion. Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try this? I didn't really get why you were using recursion as you're not doing anything that would suggest its use, and it's only complicating your wished behavior.

```
function callFor(j, arrayIdColetor) {
  //disable buttons
  for (i = j; i < arrayIdColetor; i++) {
    draw(i, arrayIdColetor, function(){});
  }
  //enable buttons 
}
```

Comment: Could you send me an example how the CallFor function should be? Tks

Comment: Oh I can't believe I didn't notice this before, I must be tired or something... You're calling CallFor recursively. A callback is not smart to do then, though why are you not just using an iterative approach here? It does not seem like you need to use recursion?

Comment: I've changed my answer to what I think would help you.

Comment: I think you're right, I will refactor it. The thing that I really need is block some user interaction while this function is running.

Comment: I did it to test:

`function callFor(j, arrayIdColetor) {
  console.log('disable buttons');
  for (i = j; i < arrayIdColetor.length; i++) {
    drawLatLong(i, arrayIdColetor, function(){});
   }
  console.log('enable buttons');

}`

And in the draw function I insert:  `console.log('draw, i = ' + i);`

The result was:
`
disable buttons
draw, i = 0

draw, i = 1
draw, i = 2

draw, i = 3
draw, i = 4
draw, i = 5
enable buttons`

Comment: Apparently it's ok, but the problem is that the draw function print a google maps polyline  according the database data. So it take a couple of seconds. So before print the polylines the button was disabled and enabled. I mean, the button should be disable when draw function started and enable just after polyline been printed and the draw function really finished.

Comment: Could you post your draw function? Maybe trim some parts of it that are not relevant if it's really big. I'm pretty sure that the part where you draw stuff you're using async functions thus allowing the rest of your scripts to continue instead of waiting for the draw function to end

Comment: `function draw(i, arrayIdColetor, callback) {
var query = new $kinvey.Query();
query.equalTo('idColetor', arrayIdColetor[i]);
var promise = $kinvey.DataStore.find('myDatabase', query);
var latLong = promise.then(function(response) {
  coordenadas = [];
  for(var j = response.length - 1; j >= 0 ; j--) {
      coordenadas.push( {lat: response[j].lat, lng: response[j].lng});   
  }
  return coordenadas;
  });

 latLong.then(function(coordenadas) { 
  $kinvey.poly[i] = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path:  coordenadas,
   ...
  });
  $kinvey.poly[i].setMap($kinvey.map);
  }); 
callback();
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98811/discussion-between-glubus-and-s-a).